# node.js returns "Cannot find module 'lockit-mongodb-adapter'"

Tags: node.js

I am going through my first node.js project. I've installed lockit , have a app.js file, and when I try to run it I get this error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^ Error: Cannot find module 'lockit-mongodb-adapter'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at new module.exports (C:\Users\xx\Documents\mailer\index.js:38:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xx\Documents\mailer\examples\mongodb\app. js:32:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I am quite certain I have lockit-mongodb-adapter installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the module. Cd to the root of your app directory and run this command and make sure `lockit-mongodb-adapter` is in your node modules directory.

```
npm install lockit-mongodb-adapter
```

Another thing you can do if you are certain it is installed is double check to see what is installed by running this command:

```
npm list
```

And this one to see what is installed globally:

```
npm list -g
```

**Update:**

I was able to reproduce the issue you where having. And to resolve it I deleted the module from the node moules directory. And re-installed with the following command:

```
npm install lockit-mongodb-adapter -save
```

It now shows up in npm list with no issues:

[image]

Comment: when i run this command: npm list, i have this error npm ERR! invalid: lockit-mongodb-adapter@0.4.1 C:\Users\xx\Documents\mailer\e
xamples\mongodb\node_modules\lockit-mongodb-adapter
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: Okay, I am going to install it and see if I can reproduce the issue.